# error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer - dev server IE 9

Tags: python, django, django-views, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

When I am testing my applications using django 1.2 and 1.3 dev server
on IE 9.  Every other requests gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmican/Envs/monetization/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
  django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 281, in run
  self.finish_response()
 File "/home/dmican/Envs/monetization/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
 django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 321, in finish_response
 self.write(data)
 File "/home/dmican/Envs/monetization/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
 django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 400, in write
 self.send_headers()
 File "/home/dmican/Envs/monetization/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
 django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 464, in send_headers
 self.send_preamble()
 File "/home/dmican/Envs/monetization/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
 django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 379, in send_preamble
 self._write('HTTP/%s %s\r\n' % (self.http_version,self.status))
 File "/home/dmican/Envs/monetization/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
 django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 508, in _write
 self.stdout.write(data)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in write
 self.flush()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 284, in flush
   self._sock.sendall(buffer)
```

error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Mainly I'm getting this error only when I'm testing with IE9

Any Solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this actually causing problems? This happens to me all the time with the dev server, and I don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens , log an error and retry the call in a loop, 
Multiple tries are required around 8 - 10 give up after that, try to put some sleep between reties this works for me.